# How to call a role using Ansible tags ??

Tags: ansible, devops

So i am having a structure like roles/base/tasks/main.yml  & another file right above the roles/ directory with name base.yml which basically calls the base role.
My problem is this, ansible docs suggest

```
roles:
  - { role: webserver, port: 5000, tags: [ 'web', 'foo' ] }
```

to call the main.yml if i have a tag defined as 'web'. I tried it but it didn't work & yes i saw a post on reddit too ---> https://www.reddit.com/r/ansible/comments/3628s8/question_about_using_tags_in_roles/

Soo is there a WAY to call tags defined in a role using .yml instead of the adhoc command , coz my deployment strategies don't allow me to run a adhoc command

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to specify the active tags other than invoking it from the command line with `--tags`.

Your example here:

```
roles:
  - { role: webserver, port: 5000, tags: [ 'web', 'foo' ] }
```

will actually tag every single task of the role `webserver` with the tags `web` and `foo`.

I think what you want instead is to only trigger the task within `webserver` which are tagged as `web` and/or `foo`. There's currently no built-in way.

There might be a solution, by creating a custom action plugin which injects tags into the `runner` object of Ansible. Action plugins are not documented at all and you will need to look at the source of some implemented actions. I once created an [action plugin](https://gist.github.com/udondan/b730206056a018cf9838) which interacts with the runner object, injecting variables. Tags might work in a similar way. If you follow this path, be aware that Ansible 2 will include big refactoring and I'm nearly sure plugins like this will break.